# Using ASP.NET Core Session State with multiple application instances

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, session

Recently, I have been learning how to use Session State in ASP.NET Core and it has worked fine when my application is running on a single instance.

As my Session backing store, I have been using the [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Cosmos](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Cosmos) package and have been accessing the Session via `HttpContext.Session` in controllers, or, via `HttpContextAccessor` in middleware and/or custom components.

I was reading the State management article on MSFT and came across:

> A better approach is to use a Redis or SQL Server distributed cache, which doesn't require sticky sessions. For more information, see Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core.

I see that I am able to use the `IDistributedCache` interface as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-the-distributed-cache) but now I am confused.

I assume that the way I was doing it before was working only with 1 instance because I was perhaps doing it incorrectly? As I mentioned, as soon as I go to multiple app instances, the application breaks.

Am I supposed to use this interface directly to get the functionality of the cache? How is my Session still associated with the cache then?

Here is how I was doing it originally:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Session.GetString(SessionKeys.MyTestKey)))
{
    Redirect('/');
    return;
}
```

Versus how I am planning on doing it moving forward:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cache.GetString(SessionKeys.MyTestKey)))
{
    Redirect('/');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the session will use the distributed cache to store the data. That means it could store and get the data directly to the distributed cache like redis or else when you add session or get the session.

When you want to get the session inside the application, the session library will directly read the data from the distributed cache.

For just one instance, if you read the session it may read it from cookie or your server's memory.

For multiple instance, all the application will read the session from same  distributed cache, this makes your session working well.

So if you have set the distributed cache and right setting for the session, it could work well for multiple instance environment.